# Sending & Receiving small TCP messages in Linux

Tags: c, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

***Setup***

I have a TCP server running on a microcontroller, and a client running on a Linux Destop.

***What I'm trying to do***

I am establishing a TCP connection, and then periodically sending messages with lengths varying from 18 bytes all the way up to 512 bytes, from the microcontroller (server) to the desktop (client).

The messages must be sent in one packet, so the TCP stack is configured to not split up the data in the microcontroller end.

In the Linux Desktop, I am using the *TCP_NODELAY* option which allows messages to be sent immediately, turning off the buffering algorithm. Good, I want this.

***What the issue I'm facing is***

I try to set the option *SO_RCVLOWAT* to 18 as well. My understanding is that when I call ***recv()*** it will return when at least 18 bytes have been received, which is the smallest messages I'll receive.

This didn't work as expected, and I don't know if it's because I'm misusing the API, or what I want to do cannot be achieved with the TCP/IP stack of the Linux Kernel.

*The problem is more with the small packages, ***recv()*** won't return with small buffers.*

***One last Note***

When running the client on another microcontroller, with the same TCP/IP setup, I can send and receive the data, how I want it, with no problems.

***How can I achieve what I want to do under Linux?***

It's for a real time application so I need the functionality of UDP but with the reliability of TCP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that TCP won't give you the functionality of UDP, even if you get the 18-byte low-water mark working.  In particular, any time one or more packets get dropped, the TCP layer will go back and resend the dropped packets, and if the resent packets get dropped, the TCP layer will go back and try again, and so on, which means that any "real time" aspects of the system will go right out the window.  If that's a problem for you, then you probably want to reconsider your choice and use UDP instead, along with some application logic to handle dropped/misordered packets.

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol. UDP is a message protocol. Also, TCP does not work well for real-time applications, which is one reason IP separated it from the predecessor to IP, allowing other transport protocols, such as UDP. You probably want to use UDP with a reliable application-layer protocol.

Comment: You might see if your networking setup can support [TIPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparent_Inter-process_Communication) or [SCTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol)

Comment: I'd recommend sctp, here is some BSD 2 clause licensed code: https://github.com/cyberroadie/sctp-examples